# Writing to a file in Python but replacing only certain instance of data

Tags: python, file, replace

I have a piece of code, which is supposed to replace a specific field in a comma delimited file. In the below example, it replaces the user to which a task is assigned to. The current user is the first field in the file. In a previous section of the code I identify the relevant line of the file I want to edit (stored as "edit_line" variable).

The code basically runs through each line. If it is NOT the line I want to edit, I just rewrite the line as is. But if it IS the line I want to edit, I use the REPLACE function to change the field, in this case the username (which gets replaced by the value of variable "diff_user").

```
with open("tasks.txt",'w') as f:
    # Go through file line by line and rewrite the data:
    for i, line in enumerate(data):
        # If relevant line (selected task) replace necessary field:
        if i == edit_line:
            f.writelines(line.replace(line.strip().split(", ")[0], diff_user))
        # For other lines, just replace with same data again
        else:
            f.writelines(line)
```

This works brilliantly, except for one logical error, but I am a newbie and didn't think of it until it accidentally happened.

The problem is of course that the replace function will replace every instance of the text that exists in that line which matches the text in `line.strip().split(", ")[0]`.

So if I have a current user called "ADMIN", and in the same line I later have the text "ADMIN" (e.g. in the task description), then both of those will be replaced by the new username, instead of just the current username that exists in the first field of the line.

I would prefer not to do a big rewrite. Is there any way I can amend the current code to just limit the writelines or replace functions to look at a specific field in the line instead of each instance? I know with replace I can say only the nth instance should be replaced, but problem is that I don't know if the valid item to replace will come 1st, 2nd or 11th... (the username field which is the first field is just one example, but there's also the ability to replace later fields in the file).

If there's no shortcut, how do I rewrite the logic to handle this?

UPDATE: Here is the entire function so someone can execute it. This code is actually part of a course:

```
def edit_task(task_number):
    class ExistException(Exception):  # Custom exception used later
        pass
    choice = ""  # used later
    edit_line = int(task_number) - 1  # Line of file to be edited (starts at 0, hence the minus 1)
    tf = open("tasks.txt","r")  # Open task file for reading first
    data = tf.readlines()
    print(f"EDIT TASK {task_number}:\n")

    # Split the selected task (edit_line) into separate fields:
    task_un = data[edit_line].strip().split(", ")[0]  # Stores username
    task_title = data[edit_line].strip().split(", ")[1]  # Stores title
    task_desc = data[edit_line].strip().split(", ")[2]  # Stores description
    task_cd = data[edit_line].strip().split(", ")[3]  # Stores create date
    task_dd = data[edit_line].strip().split(", ")[4]  # Stores due date
    task_ci = data[edit_line].strip().split(", ")[5]  # Stores completion indicator

    # Print out task detail:
    print(f"Task {task_number}: {task_title}")
    print(f"Description:    {task_desc}")
    print(f"Assigned to:    {task_un}")
    print(f"Created on:     {task_cd}")
    print(f"Due Date:       {task_dd}")
    print(f"Completed?:     {task_ci}")
    print("")


    # Check if already done, print accordingly and return to previous menu:
    if task_ci == 'Yes':
        print("\nThis task is already completed, and cannot be edited.\n")
        view_mine()

    # Give user different options to edit task:
    edit_option = input(f"Type 'DONE' to mark task {task_number} as completed.\n"
    "Type 'USER' to assign the task to someone else.\n"
    "Type 'DATE' to change the due date.\n"
    "Type any other key to go back to the main menu:\n-->").lower()

    # User selected to mark as completed:
    if edit_option == 'done':
        task_ci = 'Yes'  # change variable
        with open("tasks.txt",'w') as f:
            # Go through file line by line and rewrite the data:
            for i, line in enumerate(data):
                # If relevant line (selected task) replace necessary field:
                if i == edit_line:
                    f.writelines(line.replace(line.strip().split(", ")[5], "Yes"))
                # For other lines, just replace with same data again
                else:
                    f.writelines(line)
            tf.close()
            # Print updated task:
            print(f"Task {task_number} marked as completed:\n")
            print(f"Task {task_number}: {task_title}")
            print(f"Description:    {task_desc}")
            print(f"Assigned to:    {task_un}")
            print(f"Created on:     {task_cd}")
            print(f"Due Date:       {task_dd}")
            print(f"Completed?:     {task_ci}")   
            print("")

            option = input("Type '-1' to go back to the Main Menu, "
            "or any other key to exit.\n--> ").lower()
            if option == '-1':
                mainMenu()
            else:
                print("Goodbye")
                exit()

    # User selected to assign to someone else:
    elif edit_option == 'user':
        while True:
            try:
                # Refer to ELSE portion below. if username does NOT exist, user can try again 
                #(stored as choice, and this becomes input)
                if choice != "":  
                    diff_user = choice
                else: # if choice is still null, then this is first time entry attempt:
                    print("Enter the username of the person the "
                    "task should be assigned to:")
                    print (f"Available users: {users}")
                    diff_user = input("\n-->").lower()
                # Loop through file to check if user exists. Must count it at least once:
                if diff_user in users:
                    task_un = diff_user
                    with open("tasks.txt",'w') as f:
                        # Go through file line by line and rewrite the data:
                        for i, line in enumerate(data):
                            # If relevant line (selected task) replace necessary field:
                            if i == edit_line:
                                f.writelines(line.replace(line.strip().split(", ")[0], diff_user))
                            # For other lines, just replace with same data again
                            else:
                                f.writelines(line)
                    tf.close()
                    # Print updated task:
                    print(f"Task {task_number} assigned to '{diff_user}'\n")
                    print(f"Task {task_number}: {task_title}")
                    print(f"Description:    {task_desc}")
                    print(f"Assigned to:    {task_un}")
                    print(f"Created on:     {task_cd}")
                    print(f"Due Date:       {task_dd}")
                    print(f"Completed?:     {task_ci}")   
                    print("")

                    option = input("Type '-1' to go back to the Main Menu, "
                    "or any other key to exit.\n--> ").lower()
                    if option == '-1':
                        mainMenu()
                    else:
                        print("Goodbye")
                        exit()
                # If username does NOT exist, throw error and ask user to go to registration, OR
                # try enter username again:
                else:  
                    print("This user does not exist. Press 'R' to register them, or enter a"
                    " different username:")
                    print (f"Available users: {users}")
                    choice = input("\n-->").lower()  # store username and go back to start if loop
                    if choice == 'r':            #... unless they chose, "R" the go to Registration
                        reg_user()
                    else:
                        raise ExistException
            except ExistException:
                pass

    # User selected to change due date:
    elif edit_option == 'date':
        new_due_date = date_val()  # Calls function to enter & validate date, & returns variable
        with open("tasks.txt",'w') as f:
            # Go through file line by line and rewrite the data:
            for i, line in enumerate(data):
                # If relevant line (selected task) replace necessary field:
                if i == edit_line:
                    f.writelines(line.replace(line.strip().split(", ")[4], new_due_date))
                # For other lines, just replace with same data again
                else:
                    f.writelines(line)
        tf.close()
        print(f"Due Date \'{task_dd}\' changed to '{new_due_date}'.")
        option = input("Type '-1' to go back to the Main Menu, "
        "or any other key to exit.\n--> ").lower()
        if option == '-1':
            mainMenu()
        else:
            print("Goodbye")
            exit()
    else:
        print("Returning to Main Menu\n")
        mainMenu()
```

you need to reference to files which I name here and provide a few lines from:

**1] tasks.txt**

```
admin, Register Users with taskManager.py, Use taskManager.py to add the usernames and passwords for all users that will be using this program., 10 Oct 2019, 20 Dec 2019, Yes
admin, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each non-admin team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Dec 2019, Yes
gerhard, Test program, run through all program functions to test it, 11 Dec 2019, 27 Dec 2019, Yes
admin, Add comments to program, make sure entire .py file has comments for easy reading, 11 Dec 2019, 12 Jan 2020, No
diana, UAT, do user acceptance testing on the program, 11 Dec 2019, 15 Mar 2020, No
test, Program Sign-off, Department Manager to sign off on UAT so program can be implemented, 12 Dec 2019, 31 Mar 2020, No
gerhard, Example task, This is just an example of what a task description might look like with a duplicate gerhard, 12 Dec 2019, 14 Jun 2021, No
diana, water the plants, every week all the plants must be watered, 12 Dec 2019, 12 Jan 2019, No
admin, Test blah , blah blah blah, 24 Dec 2019, 12 Feb 2020, No
gerhard, print all, All tasks to be printed and filed, 26 Dec 2019, 13 Feb 2021, No
```

**2] users.txt**

```
admin, adm1n
test, t3st
blah, kkijh
gerhard, test123#
gerhardl, 555%%%
diana, test123
maya, 12test
jannie, password!
sannie, password123
zuma, ???
harley, test11
```

Comment: instead of calling `line.replace()`, call `replace()` on the content of the field itself.  Then join all the fields together again with `", "` to get the new line.  I would give you an answer with an example if you had provided a minimal, verifiable example.

Comment: With an example do you mean of an entire line? Here is one:

"admin, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each non-admin team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Dec 2019, Yes"

I can add more to my original question, just want to make sure I understand what you want

Comment: `f.writelines` is normally used to write a list of lines. Else it's just `f.write` (plus linefeed)

Comment: I mean code I can actually execute myself.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  Otherwise I have to recreate your runtime scenario myself before I can answer your question.  Sometimes I have the time to do so, but not today.

Comment: Updated the question... sorry, it's a bit messy will try to clean up now, just figuring out stack's editing logic

Comment: @DanielFarrell your answer guided me to figuring this out thanks. Just went super manual and build up the entire line again from scratch instead if using replace.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've said you do not want to change your code. However the solution I can think about is by using pandas.

You can read the csv file storing it into a dataframe, then you can access your username column and replace only its value. It would be something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the csv
df = pd.read_csv('my_old_file.csv')

# Update the desired row
df.loc[edit_line,'username'] = diff_user

# Save the new dataframe
df.to_csv('replaced_value.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional `count` argument in the `replace` function:

```
str.replace(old, new[, count])
Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
```

Comment: As mentioned, I don't know what the counter is of the value I want to replace.

Comment: As mentioned, I don't know what the counter is of the value I want to replace.